# Excel Conditional Formatting Escaping a Question Mark

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting, escape-characters

I would like to use a conditional formatting rule in an excel file that would color any box with a question mark in it red. It seems that Excel is using a question mark as a wild card and will turn all cells with at least one character in them red. How can i escape the question mark?

These don't seem to work:

- "?"
- \?
- '?'
- ??

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Prefix it with tilde

```
~?
```

The tilde (~) is an **escape** character for special and wildcard characters in Excel. You can use escape characters to provide literal representations of characters that otherwise have a special meaning. You can also use tilde (~) followed by ?, *, or ~ to find question marks, asterisks, or other tilde characters  — for example, fy91~? finds "fy91?"

Comment: Prefix with a `~` ?  Seriously ? What the rofl...   Does anyone have an idea *why* ?
Anyway, huge thanks.  I'd never have figured out such a syntax alone.

Answer (score 4):

Change the rule to "cells ending with" "?". This will color all cells with a question mark assuming it is the last character.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use Specific Text   >   Contains   >   ~?
This tells excel to ignore symbol command and treats the cell as text.